# ListFragment, ListView, AsyncTask, FragmentActivity

Tags: listview, interface, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I have a FragmentActivity which implements interface, Class which extends AsyncTask, ListFragment and Class which extends ArrayAdapter.
I call AsyncTask from FragmentActivity, AsyncTask fetch data from internet and return this data to FragmentActivity through interface in onPostExecute method.
Also i have a xml file - custom item for ListView and xml file which contain fragment.

RssItemListActivity.java

```
 public class RssItemListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    RssItemListFragment.Callbacks, SubscriptionsListener {

     @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      ...
           new Subscriptions(this).execute().get();
      ...
     }

...


    @Override
public void onGetDataSubscriptions(List<Group> result) {


};
```

Subscriptions.java

```
    public class Subscriptions extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Group>> {

private SubscriptionsListener listener;

Subscriptions(SubscriptionsListener listener) {

    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
protected List<Group> doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    return CallService(arg0[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Group> result) {

    listener.onGetDataSubscriptions(result);

}

private List<Group> CallService(String token) {
    ...
    return entries;
}
    }
```

SubscriptionsListener.java

```
    public interface SubscriptionsListener {

void onGetDataSubscriptions(List<Group> result);
    }
```

activity_rssitem_list.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <fragment
    android:id="@+id/rssitem_list"
    android:name="ru.develop.yaggregator.RssItemListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" >
    </fragment>
    </LinearLayout>
```

rss_item_subscription.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rssitem_subscription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

My data contain in method onGetDataSubscriptions(List result) in FragmentActivity.
And how to bind custom adapter to list from FragmentActivity ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot going on in your question, but if all you are asking is how to bind an adapter to a ListFragment, then all you have to do is call

```
this.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

in the ListFragment. Create and bind the adapter in the onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but that is not.
I added List ITEMS in class, and in method onGetDataSubscriptions:

```
    @Override
public void onGetDataSubscriptions(List<Group> result) {
        for (Group group : result) {
            ItemContent.ITEMS.add(group);
        }
 };
```

And in ListFragment I can use this collection.
Maybe it is not good...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by it's not good for performance. is onGetDataSubscriptions being called too frequently? Or are you concerned about adding groups 1 at a time. I believe there should be an addAll(Collection) function in your adapter, that may be more efficient than adding them 1 at a time.